# How to change flyway's default storage engine

Tags: mysql, config, flyway

As per flyway's default config for mysql database, flyway uses INNODB as a default storage engine for creating "schema_version table". Is there anyway that I can set the default storage engine to MyISAM?? I tried to open flyway's jar and make a change from codebase. I also found the .sql file which creates schema_version table. But after changing that file and packaging the jar again I was unable to run the flyway. Is there any config change??? from where I can change it as parameter.
I am using community version of flyway 4.0.3

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. My customer disabled the InnoDB engine. Flyway does not let you customize the engine. It is hardcoded:

[Code on GitHub](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/77e79b1a70734cf3ef40c164a39e43f4dc030c47/flyway-core/src/main/resources/org/flywaydb/core/internal/database/mysql/createMetaDataTable.sql)

So I had to execute this step on my own. It is not that much of work:

```
private static void baselineWithDefaultStorageEngine(Flyway flyway) {
    try (Connection con = flyway.getDataSource().getConnection()) {
        if (!versionTableExisting(con, flyway)) {
            createVersionTable(con);
            setBaseline(con);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Konnte Flyway Baseline für " + flyway.getDataSource() + " nicht erstellen.", e);
    }
}

private static void createVersionTable(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    try(PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE flyway_schema_history ( " + 
         "`installed_rank` INT NOT NULL, " + 
         "`version` VARCHAR(50), " + 
         "`description` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, " +
         "`type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, " +
         "`script` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, " +
         "`checksum` INT, " +
         "`installed_by` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, " +
         "`installed_on` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
         "`execution_time` INT NOT NULL, " +
         "`success` BOOL NOT NULL, " +
         "CONSTRAINT `flyway_schema_history_pk` PRIMARY KEY (`installed_rank`), " +
         "INDEX `flyway_schema_history_s_idx` (`success`) " +
         ");")) {           
        stmt.execute();
    }

}

private static void setBaseline(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `flyway_schema_history` " + 
    "(`installed_rank`, `version`, `description`, `type`, `script`, `installed_by`, `execution_time`, `success`) VALUES " + 
    "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        stmt.setInt(1, 1);
        stmt.setInt(2, 1);
        stmt.setString(3, "<< Flyway Baseline >>");
        stmt.setString(4, "BASELINE");
        stmt.setString(5, "<< Flyway Baseline >>");
        stmt.setString(6, "root");
        stmt.setInt(7, 0);
        stmt.setInt(8, 1);
        stmt.execute();
    }

}

private static boolean versionTableExisting(Connection con, Flyway flyway) throws SQLException {
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("show tables like 'flyway_schema_history'")) {
        try (ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            return resultSet.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding modifying the Flyway source if at all possible.

Can you simply change the table engine after Flyway creates it? If this isn't possible then before using Flyway you could create the schema_version table yourself effectively faking a baseline.